Xamarin.IiOS build issue on appcenter
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/hour_glass_250x250.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/hour_glass_250x250.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/icons/rsz_round50.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/icons/rsz_round50.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/icons/rsz_black400.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/icons/rsz_black400.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/icons/rsz_1map103.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/icons/rsz_1map103.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/icons/phone370_cancel_green.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/icons/phone370_cancel_green.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/phone370_cancel_green.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/phone370_cancel_green.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/AILLogo.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/AILLogo.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/default24x24.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/default24x24.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/toolbaricon_addressbook.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/toolbaricon_addressbook.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/amber_icon.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/amber_icon.png 
  /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/icon_rss.png obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/icon_rss.png 
_CoreOptimizePropertyLists:
Skipping target "_CoreOptimizePropertyLists" because it has no inputs.
_CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles:
Skipping target "_CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles" because it has no inputs.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/AltigMobileNative/AltigMobileNative.iOS/AltigMobileNative.iOS.csproj" (1) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/Native/Native.csproj" (2:3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/Native/Native.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Common/ZW.MobileNET.Common.csproj" (3:17) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Common/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Common/ZW.MobileNET.Common.csproj]
Done Building Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Common/ZW.MobileNET.Common.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/Native/Native.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.DataAccess/ZW.MobileNET.DataAccess.csproj" (4:9) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
Done Building Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.DataAccess/ZW.MobileNET.DataAccess.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/Native/Native.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Forms/ZW.MobileNET.Forms.csproj" (5:9) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
Done Building Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/ZW.MobileNET/ZW.MobileNET.Forms/ZW.MobileNET.Forms.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/Native/Native.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/BackendNET/Net.Common/Net.Common.csproj" (7:9) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
Done Building Project Native/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/BackendNET/Net.Common/Net.Common.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/MobileNativeNET/NativeNET.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Native.Forms/BackendNET/NET.DataAccess/Native.DataAccess.csproj" (8:7) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/netstandard2.1/".
Done Building Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Forms/BackendNET/DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Forms/../MobileNativeNET.csproj" (2:3) is building "/Users/runner/work/1/s/Forms/BackendNET/Facade/Facade.csproj" (9:5) on node 1 (default targets).


**##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.**


Build is not creating on AppCenter after configuration set below after select:
sdk version : 16.5
Xcode: 15.0.1 preview
I have setup project config with sdk17 for xamarin.
But no success as xamarin support of sdk17 and xcode.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
